# Laravel show data

Tags: php, laravel, join

I'm new with Laravel or any MVC.
I created the models, I create the route from web.php, I created the view with Blade, I created the controller and fetched all the data from a single model. Now, I want to make a join or something similar.

I want to get something this:
Name | Section name | Status.

In my user Model I have:
ID | Name | SectionID | Status

In my sections Model I have: 
ID | SectionID | Active

Currently I created the controller like this:

```
public function show($name)
{
    if(User::where('name', '=', $name)->exists())
    {
        return view('profile', ['user'=>User::where('name', $name)->first()]);

    }
    else
    {
        return 'User not found';
    } 
}
```

And in my Blade I'm getting content like this: `{{ $user->name }}`

Comment: Check relations in laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm you have to define the relationship between `user` and `section` model. 
Please check this thread for how to work with relationships in laravel [Laravel Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships).

Then whenever you get the user you can load any relationship that its defined on `User` model.

In your case you are performing two unecessary database calls, so I would suggest you to check out [DRY principle](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/3-key-software-principles-you-must-understand--net-25161).

Lets say in User has one Section you define the relationship in User model like so:

```
public function sections(){

  return $this->hasOne(Section::class);

}
```

Then the reverse relationship from section model:

```
public function user(){

  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);

}
```

So now your method in controller might look something along the lines of this:

```
public function show($name){

   return view('profile', ['user'=>User::with('sections')->where('name', $name)->firstOrFail()]);

}
```

This way you eagerload the sections that are tied to that user, for more about Laravel [eagerloading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Then in the blade you can access any of the attributes from `user` or `section` model.